# How do I access a custom library's strings.xml resource?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have written an Android library (.AAR) for my Android app (Kotlin code) and I want the library to be able to return some of its build configuration values.  The library does not have a Context and passing in the App's Context, just gives me access to the App's resource files.

Comment: You should clarify what type of library (JAR, AAR) you are referring to.

Comment: "and passing in the App's Context, just gives me access to the App's resource files" -- in the compiled app, app resources and library resources are merged into one big pool of resources. You might want to include a [mcve] showing what you are trying and what your specific symptoms are.